# Modifying var type of data set in Spark using its own method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

The following is a minimal example of the problem I am facing. I have an array that I want to modify in-place as it has about a million elements. the following code works except for the very last statement.

```
 import spark.implicits._

 case class Frame(x: Double, var y: Array[Double]) {
    def total(): Double = {
        return y.sum
    }
    def modifier(): Unit = {
        for (i <- 0 until y.length) {
            y(i) += 10
        }
        return
    }
 }

 val df = Seq(
               (1.0, Array(0, 2, 1)),
               (8.0, Array(1, 2, 3)),
               (9.0, Array(11, 21, 23))
             ).toDF("x", "y")

 val ds = df.as[Frame]
 ds.show

 ds.map(_.total()).show     // works
 ds.map(_.modifier()).show  // does not work
```

The error is as follows:

```
scala> ds.map(_.modifier()).show
<console>:50: error: Unable to find encoder for type Unit. An implicit Encoder[Unit] is needed to store Unit instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
       ds.map(_.modifier()).show
```

I cannot see the origin of the problem. I would be grateful for any help in fixing the bug.

Comment: And what would you expect to see in the second output? If your method doesn't return anything?

Comment: I would like to modify the elements of the array using the method. Removing `.show` makes no difference.

Comment: `def modifier():  Frame = { ... return this }`

Comment: Thank you @Luis. If you can post it as a reply I would mark it as solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user10938362 not sure in this case, because the **Array** is inside the case class. In any case yeah, mutability and spark are a bad idea

Comment: Yeah, may bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this has nothing to do with 'var' or 'val', its about mutable data structures. The problem is that `modifier` returns `Unit` (e.g. nothing), so you cannot map on this results. You can run it using :

```
case class Frame(x: Double, var y: Array[Double]) {
def total(): Double = {
  return y.sum
}
def modifier(): Frame = {
  for (i <- 0 until y.length) {
    y(i) += 10
  }
  return this
}
```

}

But I does not make much sense in my opinion, you should avoid mutable state. In addition, I would keep case classes simple (i.e. without logic) in spark, use them as data containers only. If you must increase every element by then, you can do it also like this:

```
case class Frame(x: Double, val y: Array[Double])

ds.map(fr => fr.copy(y = fr.y.map(_+10.0))).show
```

Comment: Technically returning `Unit` returns something: the value `()` (which results in the error because Spark has no idea how to encode `()`).  `Nothing` is something else entirely.

Comment: Thank you @Raphael and Levi for the suggestions and clarifications. I would have preferred to safely modifying in-place but it doesn't look like an option.